# Is this invariant of an exotic 4-sphere trivial?

Tags: differential-topology

This is a  rather  naive  attempt to construct an invariant of an exotic 
4-sphere. Apparently, the lack of useful  invariants in this context is a well known issue. This particular  invariant is somewhat obvious which probably  means  it is useless - most likely,  always  zero. However,  I would like  to know for sure.

Consider a smooth manifold $M$ together with  a homeomorphism
$f: \mathbb{S}^n\to M.$    There is a natural  map (the suspension)
$$\phi:  \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times I\to \mathbb{S}^n$$
collapsing two $n-1$ - spheres at the ends to the poles of the $n$ - sphere, which we may interpret as a homotopy  $\phi_t: \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\to \mathbb{S}^n$.  For each $t\in I$ we have an oriented vector bundle 
$\phi_t ^* f^* TM$ on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. This bundle is obviously trivial on the ends, so  we may turn  it into a bundle  $E\to \mathbb{S}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ simply by gluing this  ends.

It is easy to see that  if $M$ is the standard sphere then    $E$ is trivial. For an exotic sphere  this  depends on the  homotopy class $\pi_{n-1}(SO(n))$ of the corresponding clutching function which may be  trivial or not.  If I am not mistaken, this construction (unlike the common one using twists)  works in all dimensions, including $n=4$. In particular,  it gives an invariant of an exotic 4-sphere in the group $$\pi_3(SO(4))\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}.$$
([M. Kervaire. Some nonstable homotopy groups of Lie groups.(1960)].) The question is, is this invariant trivial?

Comment: Can not we obtain non-trivial invariant from a standard $S^4$ by choosing some elaborate homeomorphism: $S^4 \rightarrow S^4$?

Comment: Since the map $Top(4)/O(4) \to Top/O$ is 5-connected by Freedman-Quinn, the map $\pi_3(SO(4)) \to \pi_3(STOP(4))$ is injective. So this invariant only depends on $M$ as a topological manifold.

Comment: @skupers. Can you elaborate on the conclusion? We need (1) An analogous invariant in $\pi_3(STOP(4))$ (even though it would be trivial in the end) and (2) a commutative diagram. I am not sure about either.

Comment: Replace "vector bundle" by "topological microbundle" in your construction. You get an $n$-dimensional oriented topological microbundle on $S^{n-1} \times S^1$, and for $n=4$ this is depends on an element of $\pi_3(STop(4))$ (giving (1), only depending $M$ as a topological manifold).This is the same microbundle as obtained from your vector bundle on $S^{n-1} \times S^1$ by only remembering it is a microbundle (so (2) holds).